# Swagger ApiModelProperty not working

Tags: java, swagger

I have a problem with `@ApiModelProperty` in swagger. In my model, I use `@ApiModelProperty` like this

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7142106197262010406L;

private int brandId;
private String brandName;
private String fullName;
private String webSite;
private String logoUrl;
private String note;

@ApiModelProperty(position = 1, required = true, value="")
public int getBrandId() {
    return brandId;
}

public void setBrandId(int brandId) {
    this.brandId = brandId;
}

@ApiModelProperty(position = 2, required = true)
public String getBrandName() {
    return brandName;
}

public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
    this.brandName = brandName;
}

@ApiModelProperty(position = 3, required = true)
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

@ApiModelProperty(position = 4, required = true)
public String getWebSite() {
    return webSite;
}

public void setWebSite(String webSite) {
    this.webSite = webSite;
}

@ApiModelProperty(position = 5, required = true)
public String getLogoUrl() {
    return logoUrl;
}

public void setLogoUrl(String logoUrl) {
    this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
}

@ApiModelProperty(position = 6, required = true)
public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}
```

I don't understand why `@ApiModelProperty` not working. Who can help me how to resolve this problem. Please. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you annotate your class with @ApiModel ?

```
@ApiModel
public class Brand{

   private String brandName;
   //...

    @ApiModelProperty(position = 1, required = true, value="")
    public int getBrandId() {
        return brandId;
    }

    public void setBrandId(int brandId) {
        this.brandId = brandId;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I have my class annotated `@ApiModel` and still the `position` parameter is ignored - the JSON generated in swagger-ui still has its fields in alphabetical order.

Comment: Same problem with springfox-swagger2 package in 2.9.2 version, position property doesn't work for ordering property in swagger UI.

Comment: Also the same, `@ApiModel` is specified but the field `note` is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Class should have @ApiModel annotation and field or getter/setters of class should have @ApiModelProperty annotation.

Please refer the doc link - http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html

I hope it will work.

Thanks,
Mahesh Mane.

Answer (score -4):

The @ApiModelProperty Should be field level not method level.
Move those annotations to top level where you have the variable declaration.

Comment: According to SwaggerAnnotations code https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-annotations/src/main/java/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.java#L27 the @ApiModelProperty could be used on field and method level.