# Kongchen Swagger is ignoring the @ApiModelProperty annotation

Tags: java, annotations, swagger

I've tried to add more information on my Swagger documentation, but I'm having some issues with the `@ApiPropertyModel` annotation in specific.

It doesn't matter what I try to do, it just doesn't work. The plugin is generating the `Swagger.json` correctly, all the `@ApiOperation` annotations are working for the REST resources, but for the model part, it only introspects the model classes' properties and doesn't look at the annotations above them.

Here is how the plugin is configured:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>

    <configuration>
        <apiSources>
            <apiSource>
                <locations>
                    <location>com.example.rest.resources</location>
                    <location>com.example.rest.model</location>
                </locations>
                <swaggerDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</swaggerDirectory>
                <basePath>/path/to/the/api</basePath>
                <info>
                    <title>My RESTful API Documentation</title>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </info>
            </apiSource>
        </apiSources>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If I have for example:

```
@ApiModelProperty(example = "test example")
public String test;
```

It will generate the `test` property but it won't create any example or any other property that I set up in that annotation. The same is happening when using it in a getter, so I think that's not the problem.

Am I doing anything wrong? *Also, I looked at Kongchen's example project and I couldn't see anything special to make it work.*

Comment: It would help to know if the packages and paths configured in the POM are all correct. if you paste the package statement of the model calss, that would help. Also could you paste a whole Java model class with all annotations used on the class level?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900551/swagger-apimodelproperty-not-working

Comment: Thank you for adding that as related, but that's sad that there's no answer in that too. :/

Comment: I'm not sure I can add a snippet of the real code here, since it's proprietary code and there are some confidentiality issues. But everything is as it was supposed to be. I even looked at the example project in kongchen's GitHub.

Comment: If you ask for help, you have to provide all necessary information. Clearly something is not as it should be, else it would work. And which part is not correct, nobody on SO can tell without the full information.

Comment: Also have you tried with 3.1.4 and 3.1.6? If nothing else helps, you can also ask maintainers on github: https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues

Comment: @MagnoNascimento, have you filed an issue on GitHub for the swagger-maven-plugin project, as tkruse suggested?

Comment: @GarretWilson, I've done it even before opening this ticket in Stack Overflow, no answer since then. See https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/572

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to mess with the code again, and I've found that the problem is on the structure of the project. It has different modules, and it has a profile for the general development and a profile just for the RESTful API documentation.

I was distracted for a while and started to build the projects using `mvn clean package`, and as it had a version of the project installed, it was using it to create the documentation, and that's why it was never changing, after I used `mvn clean install` in the main source code I could see the annotation make any effect.

I'm sorry guys, it was beyond any information I could give about the documentation project, since it was something about the whole structure I'm using. But at least I'll keep this answer so the next person may be aware about this.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the `@ApiModel` annotation on your Model classes?

Like:

```
@ApiModel
public class PostRequest {

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "test example")
    public String test;

}
```

or your model package does not match what's given in the pom.xml.

Comment: No, I added it, as I said, the model classes are even introspected correctly, the fields appear as expected in the swagger.json file, but that specific annotation just doesn't work. :/

Comment: The fields would appear even without the @ApiModel annotation I think, so that's not proof.